# Type converting issues in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I have used the following dynamic query

```
EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ' + @TableName1 +' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE),120) = '+@InsertedDate)
```

An error is raised:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016-10-13' to data type int.

I was trying to parameterize my sql query but when I tried using variable name for the table name it was displaying the above message

If I do not use EXEC the same query is working fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM TableName  
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE), 120) = @InsertedDate
```

These are the variable types

```
Declare @InsertedDate nvarchar(50);
Declare @TableName1 nvarchar(500);
```

Am I doing something wrong in the syntax or is it not possible at all?

Comment: I don't remember when 'AND' became part of SELECT list.

Answer (score 1):

I will do this using `parameterized queries`

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SET @SQL ='SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ' + Quotename(@TableName1) + ' Where CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE) = @InsertedDate'

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @SQL,
  N'@InsertedDate DATETIME',
  @InsertedDate = @InsertedDate
```

Few changes I made

- Added `Where` clause missing in your code.
- Added `QUOTENAME` function to avoid SQL Injection
- parameterized the query again to avoid SQL Injection
- Removed unnecessary `Convert` function

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding quotes as below

```
EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TableName1 +' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE),120) = '''+@InsertedDate + '')
```

Else you can add parameter and send that parameter to sp_executesql

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax issue's

1. Missing `WHERE` clause in SQL query
2. You need to wrap `@InsertedDate` date in single quote's, try below string

   ```
   EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TableName1 +' WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE),120) = '''+@InsertedDate+'''')
   ```

Comment: Best advise to use `... ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName1) + ' ...` to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these type of problems i will simply use Replace function to build query with parameters like below.

```
    DECLARE @TableName1 VARCHAR(10)='MYTABLE' , @InsertedDate VARCHAR(20)='''2016-01-01'''

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableName1  
    WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(InsertedDate AS DATE),120) = @InsertedDate'

    SELECT @SQL =  REPLACE (@SQL,'@TableName1', @TableName1);
    SELECT @SQL = REPLACE (@SQL, '@InsertedDate', @InsertedDate);

    EXEC(@SQL)
```